# screen (html page) juddering vigorously while scrolling up or down due to pull to refresh hook on phonegap (onsen ui)

Tags: angularjs, css, cordova, phonegap-build, onsen-ui

I finally finished my phonegap app. I put the config.xml file and all my html, css and js files in a folder and uploaded it to phonegap build. I downloaded the ipa file to test it on my iphone.

The app has a page where articles are loaded from a json page that I am hosting on a server. The articles load properly. However when I hold the screen and scroll up or down, the screen starts shaking vigorously. I looked at other forums to see but all I found is DisallowOverscroll. But DisallowOverscroll set to true makes sure that the screen doesn't bounce if scrolled entirely to the bottom or to the top. But my problem is once I put my finger on the screen and scroll down, the page starts shaking up and down. I tried everything for the past two days but nothing worked. Any help is really appreciated.

I also made a video to make it easier. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O-Nd4ntZ46E

**EDIT: I figured that the problem is arising from pull hook feature (pull to refresh. When I tested the page without the pull to refresh hook, it is working absolutely fine. But I am not sure how to use pull to refresh hook and not make the page judder at the same time.**

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle with your html / javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Theres a mistake on your resolution for iPhone 6, it should be 750 x 1334, also check the image file is the correct size too.

You'll need to show code for the other problem.

Comment: Oops. I am not sure if the shaking issue is my code issue or its phonegap build issue. When I test the app on the phonegap developer app, it is not shaking. But when I build it and try it on my phone, then it is shaking. App id on the phonegap build is 1482060. Please let me know if you still want the code as I think you would understand more if you take a look at the app. Let me know :)

Comment: Changing the image size worked. Thank you. I created a video so that it would be easier to understand what I meant by when I said the screen is juddering.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O-Nd4ntZ46E

Comment: I think I understood where the problem is arising from. I am using onsen ui framework. I am using pull hook on the top of the page to refresh the page when scrolled all the way to the top. When I removed the pull hook from the page, the page is working fine without any bouncing. But I am not sure how to use pull hook and not make the page bounce.

Comment: I am having the same issues. Has anyone found a solution?